# Error 401 when calling a rest api from javascript

Tags: javascript, rest-api, rest

I'm working on an integration of a web page that will consume a rest service to create a service request (in the BMC Heli xRemedyforce application)

When I run the rest on Postman, it's going smoothly, but when I'm testing on HMTL+JS, I'm always getting a 401 error.

I don't know if the error is in my code or if it is a restriction in salesforce. Below, I'm sharing the code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test POST Rest API</title>
        
        <button type="submit" onclick="post()">POST</button>
        
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            async function post() {
                const response = await fetch('https://inforegis--trnmnto.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/BMCServiceDesk/1.0/ServiceRequest', {
                    mode: 'no-cors',
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer <XXXX>',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                    },
                    body:{"Fields": [{"Name": "requestDefinitionId","Value": "a3Hf0000000lTNaEAM"},{"Name":"client","Value": "0053j00000A7rWLAAZ"}],"Answers": [{"QuestionId": "a3Df0000000qI63EAE","Values": [ "Reclamação" ]},{"QuestionId": "a3Df0000000qHvsEAE","Values": [ "Solicitação de Serviço aberta por qualquer integração web" ]},{"QuestionId": "a3Df0000000qHwREAU","Values": ["Web"]}]}
                });
                const myJson = await response.json(); //extract JSON from the http response
                // do something with myJson
                console.log(myJson)
                return myJson
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
    </body>
</html>
```

EDITED

Now, I have created a personal domain and installed a SSL on it. Then I update the CORS with my domain

[image]

[image]

Comment: If that's a real Bearer Id, make sure you log out of it immediately. P.S. If that's exactly your code, the `<` and `>` in the bearer Id should not be there.

Comment: Yes, this is the real bearer. I have tested from postman just now

Comment: If you care about your account, **log out** of it before someone decides your user doesn't belong to you. Never post secrets in a public forum.

Comment: Ok, changed it. But what about my issue? I have cleaned the <> and paste the new section id, but same 401 error

Comment: You may need to add your site to [CORS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/extend_code_cors.htm) to work.

Comment: I recently created a domain for me, it has already been propagated and I have already installed ssl.

I put the URL just now in CORS. continues to give 401 error.

Comment: + I have commented the line mode: no-cors on meu code and now getting ERROR 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not send `Authorization` header with `no-cors` mode. This request can only be sent with `CORS` policy enabled. In order to resolve this issue, it's needed to [add CORS on your Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.extend_code_cors.htm&type=5) account as the request's origin.